# Compiler variance for overloading over array reference parameters

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

The following program is, as expected, accepted by both GCC, Clang and MSVC (for various compiler and language versions):

```
// #g.1: rvalue reference function parameter
constexpr bool g(int&&)       { return true; }

// #g.2: const lvalue reference function parameter
constexpr bool g(int const&)  { return false; }

static_assert(g(0), ""); // OK: picks #g.1
```

The similar case but for overloads over an *array* {rvalue, const lvalue} reference parameter is, however, rejected by GCC, whilst it is accepted by Clang and MSVC:

```
#include <cstddef>

// #f.1: rvalue ref overload
template<std::size_t size>
constexpr bool f(int (&&)[size])      { return true; }

// #f.2: lvalue ref overload
template<std::size_t size>
constexpr bool f(int const (&)[size]) { return false; }

static_assert(f({1, 2, 3}), ""); // Clang: OK    (picks #f.1)
                                 // MSVC:  OK    (picks #f.1)
                                 // GCC:   Error (picks #f.2)
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/v59MEj13x).

At first glance this looks like a GCC bug, but I'd like to be sure.

#### Question

- Which compiler(s) is(/are) right here?

Comment: In your first example, you have `const T&&` instead of just `T&&`. It usually doesn't make sense to have a const rvalue reference, since (1) `T&&` but not `const T&&` is a forwarding/universal reference, and (2) an actual rvalue reference to an object is typically used when one wants to take resources from that object and thus change it.

Comment: @jjramsey I know, I intentionally added const to the first example to make it an rvalue reference (edit based on user177..’s observation above: I mistakenly thought #f.1 was a forwarding reference; this was the minimal on-phone fix to change the reference example #g.1 into an rvalue overload).

Comment: @jjramsey Back on computer, so updated Q&A to remove the needless type template parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### GCC is wrong

Since the argument is an initializer list, special rules apply, as per [[over.ics.list]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.list#1):

> When an argument is an initializer list ([dcl.init.list]), it is not an expression and special rules apply for converting it to a parameter type.

As the parameter type for both overloads are references types, [[over.ics.list]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.list#9) applies [**emphasis mine**]:

> Otherwise, if the parameter is a reference, see [over.ics.ref].
>
> [Note 2: The rules in this subclause will apply **for initializing the underlying temporary for the reference.** — end note]

Albeit non-normative, this means that the call

> ```
> f({1, 2, 3})
> ```

for both of the candidate functions is (as per [[over.ics.list]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.list#6)) as if

```
template<typename T>
using type = T;

f(type<int[3]>{1, 2, 3});  // prvalue array
```

[[over.ics.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.ref), particularly [[over.ics.ref]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.ref#3), simply covers that this kind of prvalue argument can bind directly both to an rvalue reference or to a const lvalue reference, meaning both candidates are viable candidates.

We turn to [[over.ics.ran]/3.2.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.rank#3.2.3):

> /3.2 Standard conversion sequence **S1 is a better conversion sequence
> than standard conversion sequence S2** if
>
> - [...]
> - /3.2.3 S1 and S2 include reference bindings ([dcl.init.ref]) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member
>   function declared without a ref-qualifier, and **S1 binds an rvalue
>   reference to an rvalue and S2 binds an lvalue reference**

Thus, GCC is wrong to pick the const lvalue reference overload `#f.2`, as `#f.1` is the best viable function.

---

We may note that all compilers agree on the `#f.1` overload if we explicitly pass an rvalue array instead of using an initializer list ([DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/4jExfvzfo)):

```
template<typename T>
using type = T;

// All compilers agree: OK
static_assert(f(type<int[3]>{1, 2, 3}));
```

GCC's invalid behavior in the original example is thus arguably specifically due to how GCC treats initializer list arguments for candidate functions whose corresponding function parameter type is of array reference type.

---

#### Bug report

- [Bug 104996](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104996) - Overload resolution over rvalue/const lvalue array reference parameters for an init. list argument incorrectly picks the const lvalue ref. overload

Comment: Potential fix: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/compare/master...ecatmur:pr-104996

Comment: @ecatmur Nice! Is the "Please test and report back." request on the bug report intended to other GCC maintainers or to me as bug report author? (I don't have experience validating GCC fixes).

Comment: Yes, hopefully you have a more complex test case that you can try it against? (It's OK if not, of course). Building gcc is relatively easy these days; see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Comment: @ecatmur I don't have much of a more complex use case than the example of the bug report (summarized by Patrick), but I'm happy to take a stab in the weekend, as an instructive exercise.